# Mysql validate and find the wrong emails

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table for user info records, each user may have email, but suppose instead of 'a@gmail.com', system inserted `a@gmial.com` or `a@gmile.com` and the same for yahoo, outlook, and hotmail.
But now I should find all the wrong emails, and replace the wrong domain name with correct one.
Something that i have tried before, but not bring the correct result:

```
select * from users where id not in 
    (select id form users where 
         strcmp(email,'@gmail') > 0 OR 
         strcmp(email,'@yahoo') > 0 OR 
         strcmp(email,'@hotmail') > 0 OR 
         strcmp(email,'@outlook') > 0
    )
```

Comment: To clarify... You don't allow sign-up from actual [gmile.com](http://whois.sc/gmile.com) site?

Comment: Also, did you really read what [STRCMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) does?

Comment: @Álvaro González No, The system is developed long times ago and the user inserted email is not validated, now my boss asked me to change the will known invalid emails to the valid one.

Comment: It worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the similar_text() http://php.net/manual/es/function.similar-text.php php function or the levenshtein(), i.e:

```
$users = //result from select * from users;
foreach($users as $user){
    $u = end(explode('@',$user); //store the part of the email after '@'
    echo "<br />Gmail:".similar_text($u,"gmail.com",$percent);
    echo "<br />Yahoo:".similar_text($u,"yahoo.com",$percent);
    echo "<br />Hotmail:".similar_text($u,"hotmail.com",$percent);
    echo "<br />outlook:".similar_text($u,"outlook.com",$percent);
}
```

In this way, you will see the % of similarity between the emails, and then you can set the limit and replace the email for each email provider:

```
if(similar_text($u,"outlook.com",$percent) > 70){ //If the similarity is up to 70%
     $user = substr(0,(str_pos($user,'@')-1))."@outlook.com"; //change the last part of the email for the desired one.
}
```

This is only a idea, i guess is not the better way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you want:

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` 
      WHERE NOT(email LIKE '%@gmail%' 
            OR email LIKE '%@hotmail%' 
            OR email LIKE '%@yahoo%'
            OR email LIKE '%@outlook%')
```

I would also suggest to extend your pattern a bit:

```
email LIKE '%_@gmail.__%'
```

This way you check also

- There is at least one character before '@'
- There is at least a two character domain extension

Comment: SELECT '@gmail' LIKE '%@gmail%'; returns True.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to replace text is the [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
-- Untested
UPDATE users
SET email=REPLACE(email, '@gmile.', '@gmail.')
WHERE email like '%@gmile.%';
```

Repeat for each string (since it's a one time operation, trying to fit everything into a single query is just not worth the effort.)

*In case you wonder, [STRCMP(a, b)>0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) is basically a convoluted replacement for `a>b`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos()

```html
select * from users where id not in 
    (select id form users where 
         strpos(email,'@gmail') > 0 OR 
         strpos(email,'@yahoo') > 0 OR 
         strpos(email,'@hotmail') > 0 OR 
         strpos(email,'@outlook') > 0
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this using INSTR:

```
select * from users 
where
    INSTR(email,'@gmail') +
    INSTR(email,'@yahoo') +
    INSTR(email,'@hotmail') +
    INSTR(email,'@outlook')
    = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you realize that your nested query has FORM instead of FROM?

Anyway I would suggest you use LIKE instead of STRCMP.